# How to determine if nodejs child_process failed due to timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, child-process

If I do `child_process.exec('mycommand', { timeout: 5000 }, callback)`, I don't know if the resulting error is caused by a timeout or some other reason. Is there a way to determine whether the failure was caused by the `{ timeout: 5000 }` option passed to `child_process`?

Comment: The first parameter received by the callback contains an error object. Is not this what you need?

exec('command', {...}, function (error) { if (error) { console.error(error); })

Comment: The error object contains the stderr of the command, but no information that hints at whether it was killed due to timeout.

Answer (score 3):

There's only one way which may not be quite reliable.

So be careful when you use it for your needs

**How it works:**

1. When the timeout is triggered, the parent process sends out a default  `SIGTERM` signal unless you override in the options {killSignal : 'SIGINT'}
2. Once the child process is exited, the parent process's call back `cb(err,stdout,stderr)` is called by populating `err.code` to `null` and `err.signal` to `SIGTERM` or whatever it is

So you can check for `err.signal` in the callback. And again this is not quite reliable as you can kill the child process from task manager or using shell's kill command.